# How to externalise folder with electron?

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I'm using [angular-electron](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) to build a windows desktop application with angular 7 and electron 4. Now I would like to externalise a specific folder(let's say `config` folder) at the root of the unpacked build. There are a lot of files inside config folder used in the application and which could be edited by the final user

Here is the unpacked structure I want:

[image: screen]

How to manage this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `electron-builder.json` under the `build` section add

```
"asarUnpack": [
      ... your files or folders
    ]
```

Doc: https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#configuration-asarUnpack

After that, your file/folder will be inside the `resources\asarUnpack` folder.